# Reset row numbers after row sort?

Tags: java, sorting, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I am attempting to sort the rows of columns in a table model. I set the 'setAutoCreateRowSorter()' method to true for the table model I am using.

```
String[] columnNames = {"Name   (1)"};
Object[][] data = {};
dbModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
table = new JTable(dbModel);
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

The column does get sorted when the column header is click; however, the location of an entry, (row, column), does not change. This becomes a problem when I used certain methods to query the data, as the visual location of that sorted entry is not its' "real" or "row, column" location. How can I change or set the "row, column" location of entries to match their physical location in the JTable after they have been sorted?

Comment: What about using references to the objects instead of row/column indexes ?

Comment: How would I reference the objects when they are created in the constructor?

Comment: Could you provide more code? It would be helpful.
Like... the methods to query the data that you mentioned in the post, or the place where you instantiate the objects.

Comment: may be you are looking for this after sorting table is `convertRowIndexToModel(row)` which converts row index to new model's row indexes.